# Expand image on layout manager of Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have picture like this, `ImageView` size is the same as the image size with `wrap_content option`.

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/backnormal" />
```

Then I drag the edge of the `imageView`, only `imageView` is expanded and `wrap_content` is changed automatically like (*wrap_content -> 300dp*)

I would like to expand the image itself and not only `imageView`.
Is it possible??

Comment: remove android:layout_weight="1"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` attribute. There are also other values for this attribute.

Learn more here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html